# Minifi C2 server error connecting to nifi to get the template

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

when i run this link :http//localhost:10080/c2/config?class=raspi3 am able to get the config.yml file present in this path:\minifi-c2-0.4.0\files\raspi3 which is default one! but when I try to fetch the new template from the Nifi then am getting the below error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Hw9.jpg)
Can anyone tell how the c2 server will fetch the template from nifi and will it create a folder in this path (\minifi-c2-0.4.0\files) to store the config.yml file?